# How to Style Navbar Buttons Similar to Anchor Links?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have buttons in my Bootstrap Navbar like the following:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><button type="submit" class="">Tab 1</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="">Tab 2</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="">Tab 3</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

which displays:

[image]

Is there a way I can style my buttons to replicate the default style of the Bootstrap Navbar anchor tags?:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I would inspect element of the anchor tags in the navbar and copy all the css code into a class and apply that to the buttons.  I would also inspect the buttons and remove and css that is being added by default.

Comment: You can apply additional CSS. Here is just a common example of it. https://codepen.io/thomasnimmi29/pen/GWxvbO

Comment: @Nimmi - Thanks! If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it as it solved my issue for the most part.

Comment: Thanks here it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [navbar-btn class described in Navbar buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons).

If you need to remove the border from your buttons you can add :

```
.navbar-nav button {
    border-style: none !important;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Tab 1</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Tab 2</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Tab 3</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```